# Display: table-cell not aligning with the line numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have been trying to build a html page which shows a code block with line numbers. I have used CSS table-cell display property to display the line along with line number in cell format. But the line gets displayed after the line number and I want it to be aligned in the same line. CSS Grid display works properly however with Chrome it doesn't support more than 1000 lines. Please help me resolve this issue.

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: line 0;
  display: table-cell;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1em;
  gap: 0.3em;
}

.line-number {
  text-align: right;
}

.line-number::before {
  counter-increment: line;
  content: counter(line);
  white-space: pre;
  color: #888;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
<span class="line-number"></span>
<code>Code</code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `display: table` to the container tag (in your case it's pre) and `display: table-cell` to the child span

Comment: Thanks. I tried with display: table under pre and display: table-cell under line-number but it results in all of it getting printed in a single line.

Comment: can you please help by sharing the code?